# When will Alex Padilla be seated in the US senate?

Tags: united-states, senate

For the Democratic party to have a majority in the US senate, the two newly elected senators from Georgia must be seated, Kamala Harris must become vice president, and Alex Padilla must take the seat vacated by Kamala Harris.

[Another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/61814/6927) has covered the first three, but not the last.  When is Alex Padilla likely to be seated in the US senate?

Comment: It should be soon (anytime the Senate wants to) since Governor Newsom has already issued the [official proclamation of appointment](https://www.gov.ca.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Proclamation-of-Appointment-Padilla-signed.pdf) on Jan 18th. Press release [here](https://www.gov.ca.gov/2021/01/18/governor-newsom-formally-appoints-alex-padilla-to-the-u-s-senate-and-nominates-dr-shirley-weber-as-secretary-of-state/).

Comment: @Panda I saw the proclamation before asking the question, but I also noted that the senate's web site listed no senator from Georgia and only one from California.  I suppose that it's not only at the senate's discretion but that it also depends on the governor giving a copy of the proclamation to Padilla and on Padilla arriving at the senate with his credentials.  Both of those could be delayed in the governor's and Padilla's discretion, respectively, and only after they happen can the senate exercise any discretion it might have.

Comment: I see your point. The answer seems right too. Per [Ossoff's team](https://twitter.com/daveweigel/status/1351652059938959363), they will be sworn in at around 4:30 Wednesday. Regarding Georgia's Senators, it appears Loeffler is still listed as a Senator on the [Senate's website](https://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.cfm?State=GA).

Answer (score 2):

According to a [story written by the Associated Press](https://thegrio.com/2021/01/19/warnock-ossoff-padilla-sworn-in/), Wednesday afternoon:

> Warnock, Ossoff and Padilla to be sworn in after Biden
>
> [...]
>
> A person granted anonymity to discuss the planning tells The Associated Press that Harris is set to deliver the oath of office to the three Democrats after she is sworn in during the inauguration as vice president.