# What will be the makeup of the new Congress (2021)?

Tags: united-states, congress

There appears to be 2 House elections that are contested and 2 Senate runoff elections yet to be held.

What will be the makeup of the new Congress once they are sworn in on January 3, 2021? In other words, how many Senators and Representatives will be sworn in on January 3, 2021, excluding the undecided races?

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE!  Just to clarify, are you asking us to give a broad overview (i.e. which party will have majorities) or for the precise number of seats (which we cannot know at this stage)?

Comment: I’m referring to the moment the new Congress is sworn in. In other words, how many Senators and Representatives will be sworn in on January 3 before the undecided races are resolved.

Comment: You can make a guess but it has already changed as one of the elected congressman has died from covid-19. https://www.npr.org/2020/12/30/951332740/louisiana-congressman-elect-dies-after-battling-covid-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring more unexpected occurances, such as the very sad death of a Louisiana Congressman elect Luke Letlow, there will be 51 Republican Senators, 48 Democrat senators (including two independents who caucus with the Dems)

And there will be 210 Republicans and 222 Democrat Congresspersons. There are 3 seats that are still contested: NY-22 and Iowa-2 (Which are very tight, only 6 votes separate the candidates in Iowa) And Louisiana-5 Which is strongly Republican (this is the district won by Luke Letlow).  These district won't have representation on Jan 3rd.

As noted in comments,  It seems that the republican in Iowa-2 will be provisionally seated.

These are probably maximum numbers. It is possible some will be sick or self isolating or unable to take the oath for other reasons.

Comment: Where are you getting the 51-48 numbers? Is that with assumption about the outcome of the GA runoffs?

Comment: "Kelly Loeffler was appointed to a seat previously held by Johnny Isakson. The term for that seat does not expire until January 3, 2023. Loeffler will hold that seat until the runoff is decided. Either Loeffler will continue or Raphael Warnock will finish the term." https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60318/who-will-be-georgias-senators-from-january-3rd-2021-until-the-results-of-the-ja

Comment: House Speaker Pelosi mentioned this week that the Republican candidate in Iowa’s 2nd district will be [provisionally seated](https://www.desmoinesregister.com/story/news/politics/2020/12/30/miller-meeks-seated-congress-provisionally-rita-hart-election-challenge/4073901001/) on Jan 3.

Comment: It seems another member elect has caught it and will not be there on the 3rd and I am guessing that number will start to grow after all the holiday parties. https://www.local10.com/news/local/2020/12/31/maria-elvira-salazar-to-miss-swearing-in-ceremony-after-testing-positive-for-coronavirus/